# Book about alien crashing on Earth; starts "LIFE" so man will evolve & create tech to fix the ship

Tags: story-identification, books

Book about alien crashing on Earth; starts "LIFE" so man will evolve & create tech to fix the ship.

Comment: This is very brief do you remember anything else you can [edit] in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Story identification: Stranded alien ship builds Earth civilization to help it fix the spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177358/story-identification-stranded-alien-ship-builds-earth-civilization-to-help-it-f) - I probably should have looked before answering.

Answer (score 3):

This might be [Vonnegut's "The Sirens of Titan"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sirens_of_Titan). The stranded alien does not actually create life, but aliens guide the developement of human civilization to a point where humans can produce spare part for the stranded ship.

> Salo, the Tralfamadorian explorer, is a robot built millennia earlier
>   to carry a message to a distant galaxy. His spacecraft is powered by
>   the Universal Will to Become or UWTB, the "prime mover" which makes
>   matter and organization wish to appear out of nothingness. (UWTB,
>   Vonnegut informs the reader, was responsible for the Universe in the
>   first place and is the greatest imaginable power source). A small
>   component on Salo's spacecraft breaks and strands him here in the
>   Solar System for over 200 millennia. He requests help from
>   Tralfamadore, and his fellow Tralfamadorians respond by **manipulating
>   human history so that primitive humans evolve and create a
>   civilization in order to produce the replacement part.** Rumfoord's
>   encounter with the chrono-synclastic infundibulum, the following war
>   with Mars and Constant's exile to Titan were manipulated via the
>   Tralfamadorians' control of the UWTB. Stonehenge, the Great Wall of
>   China and the Kremlin are all messages in the Tralfamadorian
>   geometrical language, informing Salo of their progress.

Comment: YES!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @JohnFrancis  If this is correct, please click the "accept answer" button (it's below the up and down arrows by the answer), which marks the question as correctly answered so people browsing question lists don't wonder if it still needs the correct answer.